# How can one respond when down-voting seems to be because of prejudice and not because of content?

Tags: feature-request, downvoting

Down-voting because of different doctrinal preference.  Down-voting because of uncomfortable exposure to truth. Down-voting because of subject matter. Etc.

Is there any remedy? Is there any course of action appropriate?  Or is this just one of the unavoidable idiosyncrasies of human nature we must put up with?

Too many down-votes unfairly result in closure, deletion, etc.

Comment: It seems to me that the question is criticising the structure of Stack Exchange as such (a voting system which is private and voluntary, an elected Moderation which oversees conduct, the freedom to express individual preference by private vote of both question and answer). I don't see that SE-C behaves any differently to the other SE sites in which I participate.

Comment: @NigelJIt is not the SE system that is being criticized.  It is a fantastic creation for sharing academic and intellectual pursuits!!! Rather, it is the "abuse "of the system that is of concern.

Comment: You are making assumptions on why other people are down voting, which given your frustration is understandable.  I have found that *mind reading over the internet* is rarely correct.   Also, you need to understand that down voting and deletion are two separate functions on this site.  You can have an answer with 7 down votes that never gets deleted, for example.  Furthermore, closure has a purpose built into it: get the question up to SE quality standards so that it can be reopened.  Your question reflects some misunderstanding on how the mechanics of SE sites function.

Comment: Now, I will tell you bluntly why I downvoted this question: you made a series of unsupported assertions.  I too have been frustrated with down votes in the past (negative feedback often gets an emotional reaction, it's a human thing).  While that feeling is understandable, to attribute those actions to malice, without support, is bad form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not alone.

This Meta site contains a variety of similar questions by users experiencing similar frustrations. Though some may downplay your concerns, there's plenty of history to show that the kinds of concerns you are raising have been a problem before. I don't see that your question is challenging the nature of anonymous, community-based voting, but rather that you perceive that your posts are being negatively targeted.

To offer a positive note, my observation has been that *most* regular users on this site do not engage in this behavior; the way they treat other users demonstrates a familiarity with Matthew 7:12 and a desire to live accordingly. But a few users acting differently can certainly cast a long shadow.

**The Purpose of the Site**

One of the difficulties we run into as a site is that some users see this site as an evangelizing platform, and thus feel a need to one-up competing viewpoints. This is not the purpose of this site. This is a secular site, owned by a for-profit company, whose purpose is to make money by hosting content that generates lots of traffic.

In fairness to Christianity Stack Exchange's evangelists, they are probably acting with the best of intentions - they see those of us who disagree with them as lost souls in need of rescue. If I try to look at their actions in the best light possible (and maybe squint just a little), I can see their calls to repentance as an act of love. And there very well may be settings where such actions are entirely appropriate...but this site isn't really one of them.

If Christianity Stack Exchange were to come out in open support of one particular Christian denomination, and in opposition to all others, it would be shut down by its owners for failing to meet the purpose for which it was created (they make money by attracting lots of internet traffic--alienating millions of potential users by taking sides in sectarian debates won't help), and this would deprive the digital world of a very useful platform for discussing & learning about Christianity.

**Some Debate Theory**

This site isn't necessarily closed to debate--it can, in fact, foster very rigorous debate. But there are effective ways to debate (e.g. post an answer that answers the OP and offers a rebuttal to a previous answer), and ineffective ways to debate (e.g. arguing in the comments, ganging up on a less popular viewpoint to ensure by weight of votes that their views are always at the bottom of the page).

Now, if I'm debating someone and my position is clearly stronger than theirs, I *want* everybody to see both sides of the argument, I *want* people to be able to easily compare the arguments for themselves. It's only if I'm insecure in my position that it makes sense for me to try to bury the other viewpoint so nobody sees it (this is why shouting down speakers at public events is a tacit admission that the speaker's argument is rational and the opposing argument is not--the only defense remaining is to try to prevent anyone from hearing the argument). When people try to shut down opposing viewpoints on Stack Exchange much the same impression is created.

As the old debate adage goes, "When the facts are on your side, pound the facts. When the facts are not on your side, pound the table". So if people are trying to bury your viewpoint, take it as a complement that they don't know how to defeat your position on the merits.

**Some thoughts on helpful/unhelpful habits**

- Writing a stellar question on this site is something of an art. Questions that are too vague or too broad generally get closed because they do not work well in this forum. A potentially helpful rule of thumb - if it took only 60 seconds to write a question, the question probably needs more thought. Look at existing popular questions (you can find questions that earned the "Nice Question" or "Good Question" badge [here](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/help/badges), and/or users who ask lots of successful questions ([Inquisitive badge](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/help/badges/106/inquisitive), [Socratic badge](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/help/badges/107/socratic)) for inspiration on how to construct a question.
- Well-scoped questions get better answers. Whose perspective do you want? A format that has been used many times here is "How do Christians who believe X respond to Y?"
- If you ask a question that challenges someone's viewpoint, be prepared for a rigorous response. Sometimes users ask "gotcha" questions in hopes of making someone they dislike look bad. They then become most disappointed when said someone offers a solid response. They didn't ask the question because they wanted a coherent response...so they probably shouldn't have asked the question in the first place
- Some question-askers will give an upvote to anyone who sincerely tries to answer their question. This encourages participation, and the question-askers who do this get a lot more responses
- [Serial downvoting](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260841) is bad for the site. Those who do it want to send the message "your kind aren't welcome here" (you know, exactly what Jesus always went around saying), in hopes of pushing people they don't like away from the site. This is at odds with the purposes of the site (see above), so the site analytics look for these patterns and reverse such votes.
- However, more clever viewpoint-targeting-downvoters will space their votes so the site analytics don't catch them. Several of us on the site who know full well what it's like to be on the receiving end of this will deliberately upvote posts that are being viewpoint-targeted to a) to help foster the community this site needs & b) to discourage this behavior. If I downvote 3 posts from the viewpoint of denomination X, you see what I am doing, and you upvote all 3, the user who wrote them gets -6 points for the downvotes and +30 points for the upvotes, and the net effect of my decision to be a bully is +24 points for the targeted user.

**Conclusion**

I'm sorry if you felt unwelcome. I reviewed your recent questions and offered the notes in the previous section in hopes of helping you craft your questions in a way that they have the best chance of succeeding on the site.

I think most users on the site have good intentions. We're also all humans with biases, and it's a lot harder to recognize the bias when I'm in the majority and those biases exist in a personal blind-spot (I am in the majority on some views and in the minority on others, and I've caught myself in the past using votes to overwhelm a minority view--I have since tried, imperfectly, not to do that).

So what do we, as biased humans, do about it? I don't claim to have a silver bullet here, but at the very least, if I know I have a blind-spot, it's probably wise to do the same thing I do in a car--pause for a moment to look at my blind-spot before cutting somebody off.

Comment: -Excellent answer, thorough and amiable!  All anyone asks is a fair hearing based on the pertinent facts--pro or con, and not on presumptive opinions.  Remember the TV program, Dragnet, where the detective always asked, "Just the facts, ma'am, just the facts!"  That way people can come to Truth, and make informed decisions, to expand their understanding, or maintain their present position. Peace.